# jQuery parsing JSON results returned from controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to parse JSON results, containing status or error messages, returned from controller method or custom exception filter and display the messages.

```
     $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/LogOn",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);     
        }
    });
```

I think that with this code I can do it for a specific Action Result or method. Is there a way to do this for every JSON result returned to the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this for every possible JSON returned by your controller actions because the structure will be different and the properties of this `result` variable won't be the same.

The correct way would be to have a custom error handler which will intercept all exceptions and wrap them in a well defined JSON structure. Then you could use the error callback in the AJAX request to handle this case.

```
public class AjaxErrorHandler : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    ErrorMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message
                },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

which could be registered as a global action filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AjaxErrorHandlerAttribute());
}
```

and on the client you could also have a global AJAX error handler for all AJAX requests on the same page:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.response);
    alert(json.ErrorMessage);
});
```

Comment: How to you throw the exception? I tried                              [HttpPost]
[AjaxErrorHandler]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  //some code
  if(blabla)
  throw new Exception("blaBla"); }    But it did not work.

Comment: I tried with Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm. The exception goes through the AjaxErrorHandler, but the global Ajax error handler on the client does not show the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/LogOn",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);     
    }
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        //your logic
    }
});
```